# How to properly generate a list of String through list comprehension in Haskell?

Tags: string, list, haskell, char

I need to use List Comprehension to generate a list like this one: ["AaBB", "AbBB", "AcBB", "AdBB", "AeBB", "AfBB","AgBB"]. But I've been running into some problems creating a expression to do it

I've tried to create a list which every element would be a string concatenation, something like this "A" + x + "BB" where x is a element from a range of letters starting with "a" and ending with "g"

```
module C where
    genList :: [String]
    genList = [ "A" ++ x ++ "BB" | x <- ["a" .. "g"]]
```

So, I was expecting to generate a list similar to the one asked in the problem. But instead I just got this compiling error:

```
Prelude> :l exC
[1 of 1] Compiling C                ( exC.hs, interpreted )

exC.hs:3:41: error:
    • No instance for (Enum [Char])
        arising from the arithmetic sequence ‘"a" .. "g"’
    • In the expression: ["a" .. "g"]
      In a stmt of a list comprehension: x <- ["a" .. "g"]
      In the expression: ["A" ++ x ++ "BB" | x <- ["a" .. "g"]]
  |
3 |     genList = [ "A" ++ x ++ "BB" | x <- ["a" .. "g"]] 
  |                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^
Failed, no modules loaded.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use the `..` syntax to build a list of strings. Luckily, you're using it for single-character strings here, so you can just use it to build a list of characters instead: `[ "A" ++ x : "BB" | x <- ['a' .. 'g']]`

Comment: To expand on this (I had just started on my own answer, now redundant, but I believe this point may be helpful to the OP): as the error message says, the `..` syntax is only defined for members of the [Enum](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Enum)  typeclass. Specifically it's syntactic sugar for the [enumFromTo](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:enumFromTo) function. And there's a very good reason why `Char` is an instance of `Enum` while `String` isn't. What would you say the "next" string after say "hello" is?

Answer (score 0):

`String`s are not an instance of the [**`Enum`** typeclass](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Enum). Stricly speaking one *could* make it an instance, but that would likely not be beneficial much. Since that would yield `"a"`, `"a\NUL"`, `"a\NUL\NUL"`, etc. if we yield these in lexicographical order.

You probably want to use a `Char`acter here, like [@JosephSible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57749991/67579) wrote in his answer:

```
[ 'A': x : "BB" | x <- ['a' .. 'g']]
```

or we can make use of a functor map here:

```
('A':) . (:"BB") <$> ['a' .. 'g']
```

This gives us:

```
Prelude> ('A':) . (:"BB") <$> ['a' .. 'g']
["AaBB","AbBB","AcBB","AdBB","AeBB","AfBB","AgBB"]
```